# How to display and save extension attributes on Magento 2 Admin create order page

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, adminhtml, extension-attributes

I have created extension attributes to order for rest API services. Also, I'm able to display the attributes on the order grid.

**How can I display the same attributes on admin create order form and save it?**

Here is my extension_attributes.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface">
        <attribute code="delivery_day_slot" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>

    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
        <attribute code="delivery_day_slot" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

And, I'm saving the data using plugin

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
    <plugin name="NM_save_delivery_slot_in_quote" type="<Namespace>\<ModuleName>\Plugin\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

Namespace\ModuleName\Plugin\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement

```
namespace <Namespace>\<ModuleName>\Plugin\Checkout\Model;

class ShippingInformationManagement
{
    protected $quoteRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationExtensionFactory $shpExtensionFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->shpExtensionFactory = $shpExtensionFactory;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject
     * @param $cartId
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
     */
    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
    ) {

        $extensionAttributes = $addressInformation->getExtensionAttributes();
        $shipExtension = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->shpExtensionFactory->create();

        $payload = \file_get_contents("php://input");
        $attr = json_decode($payload, true);
        if(isset($attr["extension_attributes"])){
            $deliveryDaySlot = $attr["extension_attributes"]["delivery_day_slot"];

            $addressInformation->setDeliveryDaySlot($deliveryDaySlot);
            $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
            $quote->setDeliveryDaySlot($deliveryDaySlot);

        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Can any one please suggest a best approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you found any solution for that ?